# I need to delete the space after product description in woo commerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a huge space after my product description on the product page, I need to get rid of it but I cannot figure it out! check out the link for example

http://healthgasm.com/product/level-1-kick-start-to-healthgasm/

Comment: Hi Daniel, this empty space is for related products. Disable "related products" feature (I suppose you should look for it in your Healthgasm theme) and this space should disappear. It may be also possible for each product, I am not familiar with Healthgasm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted to hide that "related products" section below the product description.
You should add some CSS

```
section.related.products {
  display: none;
}
```

or at least this is what I did using chrome Dev Tools. Use it, it's very powerful.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I thought it might have something to do with the related products section as i used this                                                         .related.products {
visibility:hidden;
}  but i didn't completely remove the box. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

you can use hooks to remove related products on single product page.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );

add_filter('woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', '__return_empty_array', 100);
```

[reference](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/disable-related-products-woocommerce-product-pages/)